# FTPSClient: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, ssl, ftp, apache-commons-net, ftps

I am trying to connect to my FTPS over explicit server to upload a file using the `FTPSClient` class in the Apache Commons Net library using Java. It is a Windows Filezilla Server and I can connect/upload/download to it normally with a username/password using a Filezilla or WinSCP client. I can connect to and log into the server, but when I try to upload a file with the `FTPSClient.storeFile(file)` method, it crashes. The error is below.
So far I've tried mixing  instantiating the `FTPSClient` in different ways, such as giving it an empty SSLContext to not have to deal with certificates, specifying the boolean `isImplicit` in the contructor for `FTPSClient` to be `false`, setting the buffer size of the `FTPSClient` to be twice as large as the size of the file I am uploading (usually not larger than 1MB), and sending some various FTP commands such as `TYPE I` or `A`. I can connect and log into the server, but it crashes as soon as I try to upload the file. My best guess is that I am not sending the data encrypted under SSL, or some certificate issue (but that would probably prevent me from connecting to the server in the first place?), but I don't know how to make sure I am uploading the file under SSL. Most examples I have seen, such as [this one](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_2_2/src/main/java/examples/ftp/FTPSExample.java) on Apache's website, don't seem to directly use any encryption.

This is my most recent attempt, with the empty SSLContext. I have commented out other instantiations I have tried that did not work.

```java
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File uploadingFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String hostname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hostname?");
String port = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Port?");
String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Username?");
String uploadPath = "\\path\\to\\file";

try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException{}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException{}
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
    };
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);

    FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient(sslContext);
    //FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient("SSL", false);
    //FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient(false);
    //ftps.setAuthValue("SSL");
    ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(System.out));
    //ftps.setBufferSize((int)(uploadingFile.length()*2));
    ftps.connect(hostname, port);
    //ftps.execAUTH("TLS");
    if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftps.getReplyCode())) {
        ftps.disconnect();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FTPS server refused connection.", "MyFTPSClient", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    String password = promptPassword();
    while(!ftps.login(username, password)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect password.", "MyFTPSClient", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        password = promptPassword();
    }
    ftps.execPBSZ(0);
    ftps.execPROT("P");
    //ftps.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
    ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftps.changeWorkingDirectory(uploadPath);
    //ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(uploadingFile);
    if(ftps.storeFile(uploadingFile.getName(), fileStream)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File successfully uploaded.", "MyFTPSClient", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not successfully uploaded.", "MyFTPSClient", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    fileStream.close();
    ftps.logout();
    ftps.disconnect();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error caught by MyFTPSClient."); e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the console output, with sensitive information redacted with `<>`.

```
220-My FTPeS server.
220 <WELCOME MESSAGE>
AUTH TLS
234 Using authentication type TLS
USER <USERNAME>
331 Password required for <USERNAME>
PASS <PASSWORD>
230 Logged on
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ=0
PROT P
200 Protection level set to P
CWD \path\to\file
250 CWD successful. "/path/to/file" is current directory.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (<INTERNAL IP ADDRESS>,82,99)
[Replacing site local address <INTERNAL IP ADDRESS> with <EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS>]
STOR testImage.jpg
150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/path/to/file/testImage.jpg"
Error caught by MyFTPSClient.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:646)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:657)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:643)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:2034)
    at main.MyFTPSClient.main(MyFTPSClient.java:98)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

This is the output of the Filezilla server.

```
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:22 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:22 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> 220-<WELCOME MESSAGE>
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:22 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> 220 <HOSTNAME>
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:22 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> AUTH TLS
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:22 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> 234 Using authentication type TLS
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:22 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> SSL connection established
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> USER <USERNAME>
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> 331 Password required for <USERNAME>
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.1)> PASS ***************
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 230 Logged on
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> PBSZ 0
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 200 PBSZ=0
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> PROT P
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 200 Protection level set to P
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> CWD \path\to\file
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 250 CWD successful. "/path/to/file" is current directory.
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> PASV
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (<INTERNAL IP ADDRESS>,82,57)
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> STOR testImage.jpg
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/path/to/file/testImage.jpg"
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:30 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> 450 TLS session of data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection
(000006)5/13/2016 12:39:31 PM - <USERNAME> (192.168.1.1)> disconnected.
```

I enabled debugging with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` as per recommendation. Most of it looks like blocks of successful encryption and decryption. The following is a block of the debug output that seems to show that the en/decryption didn't have a complete in/output.

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
[Raw write]: length = 85
0000: 16 03 03 00 50 54 87 BA   78 CB D2 AF 8A B8 25 7A  ....PT..x.....%z
0010: A8 91 92 84 81 FE 77 89   51 D0 A3 A9 43 E8 8F 04  ......w.Q...C...
0020: 8C E9 1C 4D 37 83 4C 5A   47 EB 70 A5 A4 F2 FD 21  ...M7.LZG.p....!
0030: BF 46 68 76 DB 0C 9F FA   2C 47 9B 27 03 04 6C 52  .Fhv....,G.'..lR
0040: F9 65 5A 16 0B 11 EA AA   7C 4B 51 E6 D3 11 F1 1E  .eZ......KQ.....
0050: 31 04 C2 1D AB                                     1....
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
```

I don't know how it happens or what causes this. Maybe it has something to do with the `bufferSize` or the `FileInputStream` (probably not the `FileInputStream`, this looks like an encryption or certificate handshake issue). Whenever I connect to this server with a normal FTP client like FileZilla or WinSCP, it shows me the server certificate with details and asks me to trust it. This Java implementation has never asked me that and I don't know if the Apache Commons Net `FTPSClient` has anything that handles that.

It brings up the error at the same place in the encrypted information block every time, but the contents of the block are a little different each time.