# FTPSClient throw exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-net

i need help i'm trying to create the connection with the FTP'Server where i upload my file. 
i'm using below dependency with java **jdk1.8.0_45**. when i run my code it's make connection and also login but when i try to upload file it's throw **Exception** and **upload empty file**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:980)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:619)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:633)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:624)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1976)
at org.quorum.appnexusutility.transfer.TransferManager.uploadFile(TransferManager.java:176)
at org.quorum.appnexusutility.transfer.TransferManager.pushFile(TransferManager.java:220)
at org.quorum.appnexusutility.transfer.TransferManager.main(TransferManager.java:233)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
... 10 more
```

> Dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

> Below code i change the host may not work for you

```
package org.quorum.appnexusutility.transfer;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSessionContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TransferManager {

    public Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TransferManager.class);

    // SSL/TLS
    private final Integer TENSECONDS  = 10*1000; // 10 second
    private final String protocol = "TLS";//"TLS";
    private Boolean isLogin = false;
    private Boolean isUpload = false;
    private String directoryPath;
    private String host;
    private Integer port;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private FTPSClient ftpsClient;

    public TransferManager() { }

    public String getHost() { return host; }
    public TransferManager setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getPort() { return port; }
    public TransferManager setPort(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
        return this;
    }

    public String getUser() { return user; }
    public TransferManager setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public TransferManager setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public String getDirectoryPath() { return directoryPath; }
    public void setDirectoryPath(String directoryPath) {
        this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
    }

    public void open() throws IOException {
        //System.setProperty("jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret", "false");
        //this.ftpsClient = new SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient();
        //ftpsClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
        if(this.port > 100) {
            this.ftpsClient = new FTPSClient(this.protocol, true);
        } else {
            this.ftpsClient = new FTPSClient(false);
        }
        this.ftpsClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(TENSECONDS);
        this.showServerReply(this.ftpsClient);
        logger.info("FTP :- Connection try :- IP :- (" + this.host + ") , Port :- " + this.port + " Start");
        this.ftpsClient.connect(this.host, this.port);
        this.ftpsClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        logger.info("FTP :- Connection try :- IP :- (" + this.host + ") , Port :- " + this.port + " Done");
        int reply = this.ftpsClient.getReplyCode();
        logger.info("FTP :- Connection Code :- " + reply);
        if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            this.ftpsClient.disconnect();
            throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        this.isLogin = this.ftpsClient.login(user, password);
        this.showServerReply(this.ftpsClient);
        logger.info("FTP :- Login Status :- " + this.isLogin);
    }

    private Boolean makeDirectory() throws IOException {
        Boolean isDirectoryCreate = false;
        if(this.isLogin && this.directoryPath != null) {
            isDirectoryCreate = this.ftpsClient.makeDirectory(this.directoryPath);
            this.showServerReply(this.ftpsClient);
            if (isDirectoryCreate) {
                logger.info("Successfully created directory: " + this.directoryPath);
            } else {
                logger.info("Failed to create directory. See server's reply.");
            }
        }
        return isDirectoryCreate;
    }

    //  if returns 250, folder exists  and if returned 550 folder does not exist***
    private Boolean isDirectoryExist() throws IOException {
        if(this.ftpsClient.cwd(this.directoryPath) == 550) {
            logger.info("Directory Not Exist");
            return false;
        } else {
            logger.info("Directory Exist");
            return true;
        }
    }

    // upload process
    public Boolean uploadFile(File file) throws Exception {
        if(this.isLogin && this.directoryPath != null) {
            if(!this.isDirectoryExist()) {
                // call when not exist
                this.makeDirectory();
            }
            this.ftpsClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            this.ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);
            this.ftpsClient.execPROT("P");
            this.ftpsClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            // only the text file can be upload
            //this.ftpsClient.setFileType(FTP.TELNET_TEXT_FORMAT);
            this.ftpsClient.changeWorkingDirectory(this.getDirectoryPath());
            logger.info("Current Directory " + this.ftpsClient.printWorkingDirectory());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            String filePath = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8)+".txt";
            logger.info("Final Path :- " + filePath);
            //this.isUpload =
                    this.ftpsClient.storeFile(filePath, fileInputStream);
            if(this.isUpload) {
                logger.info("The file is uploaded successfully.");
            }
            // close the stream which use to store the file
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
        return this.isUpload;
    }

    // connection close for client
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (this.ftpsClient.isConnected()) {
            this.ftpsClient.logout();
            this.ftpsClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public String getDirectoryPathRandom() {
        Date date = new Date();
        LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        int year  = localDate.getYear();
        int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
        int day   = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
        int hours = date.getHours();
        logger.info("Year :- (" + year + ") Month :- (" + month + ") Day :- (" + day + ") Hours :- (" + hours + ")");
        return year + "/"+ month + "/" + day + "/" + hours;
    }

    private void showServerReply(FTPSClient ftpsClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpsClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                logger.info("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }
    // this method use to push the file from 1 server to other server
    public static void pushFile(String host, int port, String user, String password, File file) throws Exception {
        TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager().setHost(host).setPort(port).setUser(user).setPassword(password);
        // we push the fiel on the base of yyyy/mm/dd/hr
        // first check if the dir exist then no need to create the directory
        transferManager.setDirectoryPath(transferManager.getDirectoryPathRandom());
        transferManager.open(); // open connection
        transferManager.uploadFile(file); // file
        transferManager.close(); // close connection
    }

    //======================FTP=========================
    //FTP URL: ftp.dlptest.com or ftp://ftp.dlptest.com/
    //FTP User: dlpuser@dlptest.com
    //Password: bbCKucPzfr4b9YXUY7tvsNKyh
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        pushFile("ftps.xyzserver.com", 990, "macak", "Go447641", new File("C:\\Users\\Nabeel.Ahmed\\Desktop\\Study-Pending\\Detail Document.txt"));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All after lot of search and finally found the solution by reuse the method of ***prepareDataSocket*** here the code.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSessionContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Locale;


public class ModifiedFTPSClient extends FTPSClient {

    public ModifiedFTPSClient() {
        super("TLS", false);
    }

    public ModifiedFTPSClient(boolean isImplicit) {
        super("TLS", isImplicit);
    }

    @Override
    protected void _prepareDataSocket_(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            final SSLSession session = ((SSLSocket) _socket_).getSession();
            if (session.isValid()) {
                final SSLSessionContext context = session.getSessionContext();
            try {
                final Field sessionHostPortCache = context.getClass().getDeclaredField("sessionHostPortCache");
                sessionHostPortCache.setAccessible(true);
                final Object cache = sessionHostPortCache.get(context);
                final Method method = cache.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(cache, String.format("%s:%s", socket.getInetAddress().getHostName(), String.valueOf(socket.getPort())).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), session);
                method.invoke(cache, String.format("%s:%s", socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), String.valueOf(socket.getPort())).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), session);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Invalid SSL Session");
        }
    }
}
```

> Above Question Class TransferManager replace the class like this

```
private String user;
private String password;
private ModifiedFTPSClient ftpsClient;
```

> Above Question Class TransferManager replace the value in open() method

```
if(this.port > 100) {
    this.ftpsClient  = new ModifiedFTPSClient(true); // fro ftps
} else {
    this.ftpsClient = new ModifiedFTPSClient(); // fro ftp
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/b4352345068bfb2e227b2d7f921af990

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the problem with SSL/TLS protocol version issue. Go through the following post [SSL peer shut down incorrectly in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908835/ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-in-java) You should get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace the following line

```
private final String protocol = "TLS";//"TLS";
```

with

```
private final String protocol = "TLSv1.1";
```

Comment: thanks for replay but it's not work same error i'm getting in console

Comment: Can you check this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196102/ftpsclient-ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly?noredirect=1&lq=1